# How to activate translations in bones framework?

Tags: wordpress

I am using the WordPress framework called Bones. I don't know how activate the Spanish translation, I see that the po and the mo file are in the folder "translation", but for example in comments I see "Leave a reply", and not "Deja tu comentario" or the correct translation.

Comment: What language is defined in your wp-config file?

Comment: You have to use a plugin do to the translation like wpml or qTranslate and tell the plugin to use the mo files. I assume that your theme supports multi-languages.

Comment: b____ I have got this language (define('WPLANG', 'es_ES');). I can see all the backend in my language but the Bone stuff is in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution.

Put this in header.php.

```
  require_once (get_template_directory() .'/library/translation/translation.php');
```